# Correcting the space between overlapping bars

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

How do i make spaces between the groups, so that bars stop overlapping each other?.

Id thought it would automatically space them

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,ymax=400,
    %enlargelimits=0.15,
                legend image code/.code={%
                    \draw[#1, draw=none] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
                },  
    ymajorgrids = true,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Execution Time (ms)},
    symbolic x coords={R2G,Gaussian,Box,Sobel, Total Edge},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={anchor=west,rotate=90,inner xsep=1pt},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(R2G,33) (Gaussian,54)  (Box,127) (Sobel,246) (Total Edge, 145) };%CPU
\addplot [fill=teal!]  coordinates {(R2G,8.221) (Gaussian,13.3254)  (Box,14.958) (Sobel,29.935) (Total Edge, 43)  };%GPU
\addplot coordinates {(R2G,20.234959834) (Gaussian,26.492609995)  (Box,27.353843832) (Sobel,45.59262995) (Total Edge, 73.31923) };%FPGA
\addplot coordinates {(R2G,21.467651233) (Gaussian,38.359383243)  (Box,40.454379543) (Sobel,48.592629955) (Total Edge, 81.31923) };%HLS



\legend{CPU,GPU,FPGA,HLS}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could add `bar width=4pt,` to the options of the plot.

Comment: Seems like it just makes all the bars super thin.

Comment: Well you could use `bar width=6pt`.

Comment: i messed around the values, any number just makes it super thin, (just a line) . https://gyazo.com/afe8783785b93f2875a8e1a89d496b35

Comment: For example add `width=\textwidth,height=0.4\textwidth,` to the `axis` options. I don't think there is an automatic solution, you need to adjust the width of the axis, the width of the bars and the space between the bars (e.g. `ybar=0pt` instead of just `ybar` removes the space between the bars within a group) to your liking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be happy to remove this but with `bar width=6pt` I get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[bar width=6pt,
    ybar,
    ymin=0,ymax=400,
    %enlargelimits=0.15,
                legend image code/.code={%
                    \draw[#1, draw=none] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
                },  
    ymajorgrids = true,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Execution Time (ms)},
    symbolic x coords={R2G,Gaussian,Box,Sobel, Total Edge Detection},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={anchor=west,rotate=90,inner xsep=1pt},
    x tick label style={text width=5em,anchor=north,align=center}
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(R2G,33) (Gaussian,54)  (Box,127) (Sobel,246) 
(Total Edge Detection, 145) };%CPU
\addplot [fill=teal!]  coordinates {(R2G,8.221) (Gaussian,13.3254)  
(Box,14.958) (Sobel,29.935) (Total Edge Detection, 43)  };%GPU
\addplot coordinates {(R2G,20.234959834) (Gaussian,26.492609995)  
(Box,27.353843832) (Sobel,45.59262995) (Total Edge Detection, 73.31923) };%FPGA
\addplot coordinates {(R2G,21.467651233) (Gaussian,38.359383243)  
(Box,40.454379543) (Sobel,48.592629955) 
(Total Edge Detection, 81.31923) };%HLS
\legend{CPU,GPU,FPGA,HLS}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So I am unable to reproduce the [outcome of your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546357/correcting-the-space-between-overlapping-bars?noredirect=1#comment1380211_546357).

**ADDENDUM**: If you want the tick texts to go over two lines, one option is to set the `text width` appropriately.

Comment: Thats really strange, maybe its because where i placed it, i put right under  ymin=0

Comment: Just a follow up from that, if i wanted to rename "total edge" -> "Total Edge detection", is there a way for the words to go onto the 2nd line? normally it would overlap the other labels ?

Comment: @Freon You can set the `text width` of these ticks to some appropriate value.

Answer (score 2):

This is a "problem" quite often reported here on TeX.SX. For me the solution is to provide `bar width` and `bar shift` in **axis units** instead of as length. Then you just need to find a pair of these two keys that fit your aesthetics and can then change the axis `width` without changing the relatives between the bars width, separation in one group and separation between groups. But this can only be done when no `symbolic coords` are used.

And symbolic coords are (almost?) always used in conjunction with `\addplot coordinates`. For both I (personally) don't see any advantage compared to using a table (i.e. `\addplot table`) which offers much more flexibility.

So here is my proposed solution together with some other refinements of your code.

1. Create a data table from the `\addplot coordinates`.
2. Create `xticklabels` from the data table.
3. State `bar width` and `bar shift` in (absolute) axis coordinates.
4. Now you can freely scale the axis `width`.

Some related questions to yours and the answers are

- [How to decrease separation between different plots? bar graph pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412205/how-to-decrease-separation-between-different-plots-bar-graph-pgfplots/412218#412218)
- [How do I uniformly change bar thickness, box width and add error bars?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232646/how-do-i-uniformly-change-bar-thickness-box-width-and-add-error-bars/355921#355921)

---

#### Bonus stuff you could do

Having this solution so far you could even go one step further and add the `\addplot`s in a loop instead of adding them one by one. For that see the answers to e.g.

- [Graph from csv table (col sep=comma) with pgfplotsinvokeforeach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448514/graph-from-csv-table-col-sep-comma-with-pgfplotsinvokeforeach/448517#448517)
- [pgfplots: percentages and endvalues in stacked ybar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118722/pgfplots-percentages-and-endvalues-in-stacked-ybar/349210#349210)

And if you do that there remains one point that I haven't addressed so far: I removed the manual set color to the second `\addplot` command (because this is not relevant for answering your question). Of course when using the loop you can't state the color as an option to the `\addplot` command any more. But instead you can create your own `cycle list` and invoke it. For that see [section 4.7.7 in the PGFPlots manual (v1.17)](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=219) and of course you will find examples here on TeX.SX too.

Now you will perhaps think: "Why should I do all this stuff? This seems to be much more work/code than in my "simple" solution." And you are absolutely right with that. But the **real** benefit comes, when you create **styles** with all of this. Then you make sure all your plots look quite similar and also changes are done easily to **all** axis/plots by just changing the styles. Unfortunately I don't have good examples here, because questions here on TeX.SX are usually not about this topic. But I will state some very basic examples and maybe you can image how simple it is to change stuff then and maybe also, if you would combine the styles.

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383403/95441
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502754/95441
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417423/95441
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303284/95441

```latex
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    % use this `compat' level or higher to be able to provide (relative) axis
    % units to `bar width' and `bar shift'
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % step 3a:
    % define the values for the width and shift of the bars
    % (the total "width" at one coordinate is 1. So the sum of the two
    %  values should be maximum 1 so the bars don't overlap.)
    % (The values could also be given directly to the keys, but this here is
    %  more general and allows arbitrary calculations of the values.
    %  So one could e.g. also first get the number of columns in the data
    %  table and compute `BarWidth` from that.)
    /pgf/declare function={
        BarWidth = 0.175;
        BarShift = BarWidth/2 + 0.05;
    },
]
        % step 1:
        % create a data table
        % (when there is a space in a string it needs to be surrounded by curly brackets
        %  or one could use another `col sep`)
        \pgfplotstableread{
            x                 CPU   GPU       FPGA           HLS
            R2G               33    8.221     20.234959834   21.467651233
            Gaussian          54    13.3254   26.492609995   38.359383243
            Box               127   14.958    27.353843832   40.454379543
            Sobel             246   29.935    45.59262995    48.592629955
            {Total \\ Edge}   145   43        73.31923       81.31923
        }\mydata

    \begin{axis}[
%        % step 4:
%        % adjust the `width` of the `axis` to your needs
%        width=\textwidth,
        % step 3b:
        % use the above defined values
        /pgf/bar width=BarWidth,
        /pgf/bar shift=BarShift,
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=300,
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.5},
        ylabel={Execution Time (ms)},
        xtick=data,
        % step 2:
        % use `xticklabels from table` instead of stating `symbolic x coords`
        xticklabels from table={\mydata}{x},
        % (when you manually add line breaks you need to state how the text
        %  should be aligned)
        xticklabel style={
            align=center,
        },
        ymajorgrids=true,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style={
            anchor=west,
            rotate=90,
        },
        legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[#1, draw=none] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
        },
        legend style={
            % (use `xticklabel cs:` so you don't have to care about the `yshift`)
            at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
        },
        % use the `\coordindex` for all plots
        table/x expr={\coordindex},
    ]

        \addplot table [y=CPU]  {\mydata};
        \addplot table [y=GPU]  {\mydata};
        \addplot table [y=FPGA] {\mydata};
        \addplot table [y=HLS]  {\mydata};

        \legend{CPU,GPU,FPGA,HLS}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]